# $watch with the fastest performance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What is the way to write a $watch that will yield the best performance? I put together a jsperf that seems to indicate that method 3 is actually the fastest, but I wanted to see if anyone could come up with an even faster way or point out any flaw in my tests.

http://jsperf.com/watch-string-vs-deep-watch-object

```
var obj = {item1: 'a', item2: 'b'};
```

#### Method 1

```
//deep watch on obj
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return window.obj
 }, function() {}, true);
```

#### Method 2

```
//deep watch on obj that is on scope
$rootScope.obj = obj;
$rootScope.$watch('obj', function() {}, true);
```

#### Method 3

```
//create a hash of all of the values from obj, do a shallow watch
rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return obj.item1 + '-' + obj.item2;
}, function() {});
```

Comment: These are not identical. Comparing performance of deep vs shallow watch is kinda pointless, isn't it?

Comment: Also I suspect that your method 3 will put a greater strain on the GC.

Comment: The end result is the same. I am looking for the fastest way to know that obj.item1 OR obj.item2 has changed.

Comment: Whatever works for you. Method 3 doesn't scale, though. What if now you need to watch 3 properties (or rename one)? You need to touch the code. No such problems with the other two approaches. This may very well not be a concern to you, just pointing this out.

Comment: have my +1 for measuring, btw.

Comment: Method 3 not only doesn't scale, but doesn't always work. If item1 goes from "ab-" to "ab" and item2 goes from "cd" to "-cd", the watcher won't be triggered although both have changed.

Comment: @JBNizet, good point. If method 3 is used, it would be important to know your data so you can determine if it is feasible to use this method. The alternative is that instead of the '-' delimiter, pick a different delimiter, maybe something like '#$@' that is extremely unlikely that the user would enter.